# What is the appropriate word for "following trail" or similar in English?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

In this scenario, suppose someone gives me a *down vote*, for whatever reason. After that someone else comes and sees the down vote and thinks *this should be down voted*. Another *down vote*. Another person comes and does the same.

What do you call this phenomenon in English? I want to use it in an article. If it has an ironic tone, all the better.
I want to use the word as in the following sentences.

- My question again got *word* -ed (past participle).
- Everyone in this site loves *word* -ing
- Oh, another *word*!

**N.B.**: Please don't hesitate to up-vote or down-vote this question or even flag or close-vote it. This question has nothing to do about the question's status itself. I am just looking for a word. When I get it I'll accept the answer and up-vote it.

Comment: Maybe it is a "bandwagon" ...

Comment: @GEdgar I dont think its [bandwagon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bandwagon). In Bangla I call it হুজুগ.

Comment: @Danielδ Some notes added for you or other who is thinking like you.

Comment: Shiplu, note that you can read over the question edits (by clicking on the time or date below the word "edited") and the comparison may help you with knowing where to place apostrophes and how to make number or tenses agree.

Comment: @jwpat7 Nice editing. Last time I was aware about the grammar, it was the school-life.

Comment: I call it bloody annoying, personally. If you want to see it in action, pick a popular political blogger who has strong opinions on one side of politics (but I repeat myself). Read their comments, and after you've finished vomiting you'll have a good example of that mutually reinforcing rush to follow an opinion. Hilariously, this sometimes backfires. One particular columnist I'm thinking of is known for being vague so he can hold his hands up and say "But I didn't say *that*!" after being accused. Occasionally his flock of angry gnats misinterprets his hints and attacks the wrong target.

Comment: Incidentally, in Australia the act of deliberately inciting this is known as "dog-whistling". A dog whistle is inaudible to humans and thus deniable, and the pack of slavering hounds chasing the poor sod in the spotlight is in no way evidence that the whistler meant for it to happen. No, he was merely pointing out something so trite and out of context that it couldn't be denied, and he's got no idea where the vicious mob tearing the victim to pieces got their conclusions from. I've got someone in mind who does this too much, but I'm not mentioning names or sides because he's not the only one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some phrases that might be related to what you are asking are

- [follow the leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follow_the_Leader_%28game%29)
- [monkey see, monkey do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_see,_monkey_do)
- [trail blazing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_blazing) or trailblazing
- [jump on the bandwagon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect), also referred to in wikipedia as a form of *[groupthink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink)* (or [information cascade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_cascades)  as mentioned in previous answer) or [herd behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_behavior)
- *[steamrollered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/steamroller)*, flattened out by a seemingly irresistible force
- *[mobbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobbing)*, or being ganged up on

I've also seen *pirhana effect* and *shark attack* used in such a context, but from further reading gather that those terms are unfair to pirhanas and sharks.

Comment: Hivemind could be another good one.

Comment: *Bandwagon* sounds best to me, e.g., “everyone on this site loves bandwagon downvoting” or “my question got bandwagon-downvoted again”.

Comment: In addition to "mobbed", "mob mentality".

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for a verb, one is *pile-on*, so your first two examples become

- Again my question got piled-on.
- Everyone in this site is piling-on.

Comment: I heard the word *pile-on* earlier. But now understood meaning. +1

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to get *pyloned* in hockey, but I'd like to think that too gains traction from the sense of getting hammered down by a [pile-driver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pile+driver), which really does stomp things down!

Comment: Could you pile-on only down votes? Or up votes as well? What's the 'loss' in pile-on -- except gaining weight? :)

Comment: There’s an impolitically correct variant that goes with those sort of piles: nigger pile.

Comment: @tchrist: I think that may have a [different origin and meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigger_in_the_woodpile)

Comment: @Henry That’s not the same thing.  When a bunch of kids are horsing around, one will shout "Nigger pile on Jamie!" and everybody else will jump on Jamie, burying him beneath a pile of kids.

Answer (score 3):

An [Information Cascade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_cascade).

Comment: Also, groupthink, and relatedly, [anchoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring).

Comment: @Dimitris  How do I use Information Cascade as verb? Does You have cascaded the information again sound good?

Comment: I don't think so, @Shiplu. I use the term to describe the occurrence of an event, something along the lines of "an information cascade resulting from such and such conditions."

Answer (score 3):

This is **herd mentality**.

One person does something with or without reason; the others do it for the sole 'reason' that the first person has done it. Their simplistic logic is: 'If that were not so, why would the first person have done it in the first place?' -- also, 'he did the thinking for me, so why do I need to think about it all over again?'

The metaphor usually is 'sheep', after its characteristic behavior. So,

"*There comes another sheep*", maybe?

Comment: I also found those who has this mentality called [sheeple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheeple)

Answer (score 2):

You might try "blackball" :

verb

1. to vote against (a candidate, applicant, etc.).
2. to exclude socially; ostracize: The whole town blackballed them.
3. to reject (a candidate) by placing a blackball in the ballot box.

noun

1. a negative vote, especially in deciding on an applicant or candidate.
2. a black ball  placed in a ballot box signifying a negative vote.

Comment: Its not just voting. I can be something else. *Information Cascades* seems the perfect thing. But I am looking for perfect verb.

Comment: Well, since I'm not a mind reader, you're on your own. If your goal is to be blackballed, you might achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's one word that fits all the given contexts.  Personally I'd use (most of these have already been mentioned):

- "ganged up on"
- "jumped on the bandwagon" or maybe "piled on"
- "case of groupthink"

Example 1:

> Everyone ganged up on my question again!  And I thought I had done such a good job writing it this time.

Example 2:

> After I get a *down vote* it seems like everyone on stackexchange always jumps on the bandwagon and before I know it my answer is at the bottom.

Example 3:

> Oh, another case of groupthink!

Comment: Nice examples. I am keeping this question `unanswered` for a while so that I get some new answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

for the scenario you described, I believe another word might have been hen-pecked.

if in a group of chickens one hen pecks another and draws blood, all the other hens, upon seeing the blood start pecking the same hen, hence once someone throws the first stone, the rest follow.

unfortunately this word is used for husbands/boyfriends that are constantly nagged by their wives/girlfriends.

shame, it would have been an ideal match :)